# PHP - array_diff One multidimensional array and one flat array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two arrays. One of them is a multidimensional array e.g.

```
 $products = array(
        0 => array(
            'product_id' => 33,
            'variation_id' => 0,
            'product_price' => 500.00
        ),
        1 => array(
            'product_id' => 45,
            'variation_id' => 0,
            'product_price' => 600.00
        ),
2 => array(
            'product_id' => 48,
            'variation_id' => 0,
            'product_price' => 600.00
        ),
        3 => array(
            'product_id' => 49,
            'variation_id' => 0,
            'product_price' => 600.00
        )
    );
```

and I have a flat array

```
$missingItems= array(49,33);
```

I would like to remove items from $products where their `product_id` is in the array `missingItems` string.

```
$diff = array();
foreach ($missingItems as $missingItem) {
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        if($missingItem != $product['product_id']){
            $diff[] = $missingItem;
        }       
    }   
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($diff);
echo '</pre>';
```

When I do this, all the values are being repeated multiple times. e.g. if I have 4 items in my first array, and two in my second. There are 8 results. I would like only 2 to appear i.e. those that are not present in the second array.

When I have two flat arrays I use `array_diff` but I'm not sure how to use it in this case where I have a multidimensional array and a flat array.

Comment: In your output array, should it return a multi dimensional array with main keys 1 and 2? And remove 0 and 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `array_filter()`:

```
$filtered = array_filter($products, function($product) use ($missingItems){
    return !in_array($product['product_id'], $missingItems);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> you can use `in_array()` to check and make new array

```
$diff = array();
foreach ($products as $product) {
  if(!in_array($product['product_id'], $missingItems)){
    $diff[] = $product;
  }  
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($diff);
echo '</pre>';
```

I hope this will help to achieve your goal

Answer (score 0):

Use in_array()

```
$diff = array();
foreach ($products as $product) {
  if(!in_array($product['product_id'], $missingItems)){
    $diff[] = $product;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> There's no need to unnecessarily traverse through your `$missingItems` array.
>
> [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) does the trick.

```
foreach ($products as $k => $product) {
    if (in_array($product['product_id'], $missingItems)) {
        unset($products[$k]);
    }       
}
```